# PHP BLENC extension security concern

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, php, c

[PHP BLENC](https://pecl.php.net/package/BLENC) is a extension that allows PHP developer encrypt their code, protect their ideas and avoid illegal copy. Although BLENC allow developer to define the main encryption key in source(in the header file), I discover that they are still using `MD5` as their password hashing function. Will is cause any vulnerabilities? It is worth to rewrite it by using a modern hashing function such as `SHA256`? Furthermore, is BLENC safe to use? In other word, can it keep reverse engineering far of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After for little research, I can say this extension is not safe because I can simply extract the main key in clear text format by using any type of HEX editor. Hash function is NOT important any more.

1. Linux:

   - Offset: `0x00003158`
   - Using `xxd`
2. Windows: Unable to compile but believe the develop team using default password `0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef`

   - Offset: `0x0000355C`
   - Using `Hex Workshop`

Comment: Is there anything else that can secure my code? I found a free tool http://fopo.com.ar/. Is it safe? Thanks. @Hartman